# Strange behavior of composite background border

Tags: html, css

See this fiddle for the simplest and cleanest explanation I can offer: http://jsfiddle.net/JRyJe/2/

On a site I am working on I am creating decorative borders around certain divs.  To create the effect I am compositing many background images together, one for each corner plus a 1px wide tiled edge piece to create the sides.

Two of the three work exactly as intended.  But this one, for some reason, is having color problems in the edge pieces - the color doesn't match the background color.  I have triple checked the edge pieces themselves in photoshop (Here is a [link](http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/Nborder.jpg) to one for you to download and see for yourself) and the color is correct in the image.

So what is going on?

The code, since SO doesn't appreciate jsfiddle links:

HTML

```
<div id="about">
    <div class="deco_border">
         <h2>Why are those pinkish bars there?</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#about .deco_border {
    padding: 110px;
    background: url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/NWcorner.jpg') no-repeat,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/SWcorner.jpg') left bottom no-repeat,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/SEcorner.jpg') right bottom no-repeat,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/NEcorner.jpg') right top no-repeat,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/Nborder.jpg') repeat-x,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/Wborder.jpg') repeat-y,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/Sborder.jpg') bottom repeat-x,
                url('http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/Eborder.jpg') right repeat-y,
                #c00d13;
}
```

Comment: SO appreciates fiddle links very much, but they shouldn't be the only place to see the code representative of your issue. If something happens to fiddle sometime down the road, future users of SO should be able to gain value from reading your question as-is.

Comment: why not design some transparent image? then you can change the background color to whatever color you want. It also prevents this kind of issue from happening.

Comment: @Palpatim Fair point.

Comment: @KingKing You know, I don't know why that didn't occur to me to just use PNG's with transparency.  Actually, I do.  In this case you're right, it would work great.  But the other two borders which you aren't seeing here are a lot more complicated and mesh into a textured background on the div, so transparency wasn't an option there.  When it came to this one, I just continued the trend.  I'll keep your idea in mind next time though, that's for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be your images (even though you said you had checked them). If I view your image at source your color issue is present

http://web.fildred.com/images/about_border/SWcorner.jpg

Comment: Chalk this one up to code voodoo.  I swear AS I uploaded this to SO that I downloaded a corner and a line and opened them in photoshop, checking every pixel for color fidelity and they were perfect #c00d13.  Because I knew this was the first thing people would do.  So Dubbya Tee Eff.  But whatever, I know how to fix color fidelity so I guess I'll just do that.  I swear if I post something to SO, things magically change, or the answer becomes blindingly clear three minutes after posting.  Why can't the epiphany come before the post?  Something for meta I guess.

Comment: I've done similar things before, these things happen. Glad I could help.